# Set of layered, transparent elements scrolling at different speeds possible in only CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a set of three elements set up roughly like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="img.png"/>
    <div class="text">
      <span>Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Assume that I have simple CSS to layer them with the background being third, the image being second, and the text being first in terms of distance from viewer, and that they're all centered with respect to the topmost container. The background has a `background-image`, and all images and `div` elements are transparent.

What I'm trying to do is to have them scroll at slightly different speeds relative to the viewport. I'm not particularly familiar with CSS `transform` and `perspective` properties, but I was wondering whether this is possible in just CSS. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Sure is! You're describing parallax, done with pure CSS. Here's an [example](https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw) that might help. CSS-tricks also describes this in depth, [here](https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-parallax-scrolling-websites/)

The key is setting transform to reflect the distance from the user.

```
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.parallax__layer--base {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.parallax__layer--back {
  transform: translateZ(-1px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I have it halfway working, but the overflow is causing an issue as it adds a scrollbar in my particular setup, and also cuts off part of the image at certain scroll points. It also seems to only work when I scroll my mouse over the parallax element, rather than anywhere in the page.